# Elm http 2.0.0 functions expect constructor function

Tags: http, elm

For the http **request** functions, both [the Elm tutorial](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/http.html) and [the docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/2.0.0/Http) suggest passing a constructor function (e.g. `GotText`) to an expect function (e.g. `expectString`), for the `expect` field, e.g:

```
type Msg
  = GotText (Result Http.Error String)

getPublicOpinion : Cmd Msg
getPublicOpinion =
  Http.get
    { url = "https://elm-lang.org/assets/public-opinion.txt"
    , expect = Http.expectString GotText
    }
```

I understand this, but it seems to me that constraining the API to require  a constructor function (e.g. `GotText`) is overly restrictive.

---

For example, it is possible to use `identity` to extract the constructor function `GotText` from the request function `get`:

```
getPublicOpinion = Cmd.map GotText (
  Http.get
    { url = "https://elm-lang.org/assets/public-opinion.txt"
    , expect = Http.expectString identity
    })
```

---

But that begs the question: Why does the http API require the constructor function at all*?

* Or at least allow us to omit the `expect` field and return `Result Http.Error String`.

Comment: The only way the result of the http call can have any effect on your program is my sending the result through the update function, which you would do by using a constructor function and handling it in your update. Its not constraining, its guiding you.

Comment: If you didn't provide a constructor, the return type would be `Cmd (Result Http.Error String -> msg)` which is pretty weird. The core Elm libraries make it a point to take a message constructor instead of returning a command with a function in it.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to think the correct answer is "because conventions". Specifically: "because the Elm architecture convention" (i.e. Ben's answer), and "because don't have commands return functions" (i.e. Sidney's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a *restriction*, it's actually a **convenience**.

If `Http.expectString` didn't take a function `(Result Http.Error String -> msg)` then `Http.get` would return a `Cmd (Result Http.Error String)` which is what it does if you pass in `identity`.

Since the result of all `Cmd`s always needs to be a `Msg` that the runtime can pass in to your `update` function you would always have to `Cmd.map` the result of every call `Http.get` to convert the `Cmd (Result Http.Error String)` to a `Cmd Msg`.

To avoid having to call `Cmd.map` every time you call `Http.get` the API allows you to pass the function that will do the conversion straight to `Http.expectString`. This is less typing, involves less nesting so it's clearer to the reader.

You'll see this convention repeated across lots of modules. eg.:

- `Json.Encode.list` has the type `list : (a -> Value) -> List a -> Value` it takes a function to do the JSON encoding of the elements of the list, this saves you from having to use `List.map` to JSON encode the element of the list first.
- `Html.Events.onInput` has the type `onInput : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg` it takes a function to convert the `String` to a `msg` value, this saves you from having to `Html.Attribute.map` the result of `onInput` to convert the `Attribute String` to a `Attribute msg`. This would be a really pain if you had to call `Html.Attribute.map` for every event handler and `Attribute` on any Html elements.